# Mouse cursor flickering when streaming video in Chrome. Browser window gets grayed

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, video, cursor

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Asus laptop. I am not attaching any secondary monitor to it.

Since few weeks I noticed that when I am watching Youtube videos sometimes the mouse cursor starts flickering: it seems it's quickly switching between the arrow and the hand cursor.
After few seconds the Chrome window gets grayed out.

Please note the video is **NOT** flickering, just the mouse cursor.

I noticed also that the laptop is less responsive in in general so I am assuming Chrome is probably using more CPU and RAM.

The only temporary solution I found is to double click on the window top bar so it becomes smaller.

So far I tried

- sudo apt get upgrade
- restart chrome
- check the Display in system settings: it does not show any "unknown monitor"

Thanks!

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Is your scaling value 200%? if it is so, change the value to 175% or 150%